# ggplot color lines with consistent scale adding new color for each new line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot to plot some data:

```
## sample data
dat = data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:5], 10), 
                 idx = rep(1:length(letters[1:5]), each = 10))
dat$value = cumsum(cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), nrow(dat), TRUE)))

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_path(aes(x = idx, y = value, color = group, group = group)) +
  viridis::scale_color_viridis(option = 'magma', discrete = T)


## add more groups
dat = data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:10], 10), 
                 idx = rep(1:length(letters[1:10]), each = 10))
dat$value = cumsum(cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), nrow(dat), TRUE)))

## replot
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_path(aes(x = idx, y = value, color = group, group = group)) +
  viridis::scale_color_viridis(option = 'magma', discrete = T)
```

My issue with this is that the max and min colors are the same for both plots. And it is adjusting the colors in between.

Is there anyway to use this color scale (or similar) but always have the second color be the same? ie so that the first five colors would be the same for both graphs?

Comment: Set the `end` argument to `scale_color_viridis` to correspond to the number of groups. So if you maximum number of groups is 10, set `end = seq(0, 1, length.out = 10)[n_group_for_this_plot]`.

Comment: If you know the groups in advance you could set the `limits` (and the `breaks` as needed).  For example, in your first plot you could add `limits = letters[1:10], breaks = letters[1:5]` to your `scale_*()` function